# Do I need "RunAndBlock" for scheduled web jobs?

Tags: azure-webjobs

My intention is to run a 3 second web job every 5 min. What happens if I skip the `host.RunAndBlock`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a simple time scheduled job, there is no need to use the WebJobs SDK at all, so there is no host at all. Just use a plain console app (can be as simple as a one line Main), and deploy it as a scheduled CRON WebJobs. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs.